# content after letter-spacing css

Tags: css, typography, letter-spacing

My purpose is to have two letters in a pseudo-element's content, with a spacing of 1 pixel between each letter.

I have tried the obvious, which is assigning a `letter-spacing` of 1 pixel:

```css
#tweetList > li > .blockstyle > blockquote p.tweettext:before{
    content: '\2018\2019';
    font-family: 'ocr';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 120px;
    top: 0px;
    left: -120px;
    color: rgba(26,114,189, 1);
    text-shadow: 7px 14px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}
```

The problem is that the two apostrophes are not getting the desired spacing. Here's a snapshot of the result:

[image: result apostrophe spacing]

And here's what I'm trying to achieve:

[image: desired apostrophe spacing]

How can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Problem

The issue lies within the glyph's width. As each apostrophe letter is taking more space in width than the actual glyph, they seem departed.

#### Solution

To solve this, adjust the letter spacing by assigning a negative value, like so:

```css
#tweetList > li > .blockstyle > blockquote p.tweettext:before{
    content: '\2018\2019';
    font-family: 'ocr';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 120px;
    top: 0px;
    left: -120px;
    color: rgba(26,114,189, 1);
    text-shadow: 7px 14px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    letter-spacing: -.2em; /* <-- */
}
```

#### Demo

- [on dabblet](http://dabblet.com/gist/3524155)